# android after disableKeyguard the inKeyguardRestrictedInputMode() still return true

Tags: android, keyguard

version: android 4.4.2

I use [`keyguardLock.disableKeyguard()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/KeyguardManager.KeyguardLock.html#disableKeyguard()) unlock the screen, then use [`keyguardManager.inKeyguardRestrictedInputMode()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/KeyguardManager.html#inKeyguardRestrictedInputMode()) print screen lock state, it always return true,but the [`powerManager.isScreenOn()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.html#isScreenOn()) return true,and i can use my phone normally.

ps: I do lock and unlock in a android service.

Is there any thing wrong when use disableKeyguard()?

Comment: please clarify this *then use keyguardManager.inKeyguardRestrictedInputMode() print screen lock state*  (i.e. what does it you mean ?)

Comment: when the phone unlock by my app, other app read lock state by call `inKeyguardRestrictedInputMode()`,and then they thought my phone was locked, they may do something strange thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The keyguardLock is deprecated starting from API 13. Please use the FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD and/or FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED. See [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/KeyguardManager.html)

Comment: I had read the document,but how can I use getWindow() in a service?

Comment: You can't. I think you are using a keyguard lock in order to unlock it to show something to the user, isn't it? Than you have to put getWindow() stuff there (i.e. in your activity shown).

Comment: I use `BroadcastReceiver` in a service, when I close to the proximity sensor,it send a broadcast,my MainActivity will catch this broadcast,then call `getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD)` to unlock my phone, but actually the screen is on,but my phone is still locked

Comment: The getWindow() stuff must be called in onCreate() callback when the activity is created. Other important point: this flags works only if the activity has a "normal" theme. I mean they don't work if you use a dialog theme.

Comment: I want use proximity sensor to control screen on/off,and lock/unlock,so I need a service listenning proximity sensor after main activity disappeared, but how can I call the `onCreate()` callback method of `MainActivity`?

Comment: When you need to unlock the screen call startActivity() with your activity. Maybe you need a full screen and transparent activity to do the trick.

Comment: @greywolf82 If it's deprecated, what should I use instead of inKeyguardRestrictedInputMode ?